# o1.equals(Object o2) operator causing error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop a small android app and I ran into this rather "weird" problem, I need to compare two strings and do few things if they match, I used == operator first, and even if the 2 strings were the same, my if statement treats them as not equal and just moves on to next statements (I know the two strings are equal because I watch their values and debug step-by-step). So I tried to use .equals operator instead, but it's giving me StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on the previous two statements which are:

```
String s1 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\t"));
String s2 = subjectName.substring(0, subjectName.indexOf("\t"));
```

Here is a screenshot of step-by-step debugging, both s1 and s2 has a value "Mathematics" but the if statement ignores it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofHZY.png)

Here is a more "complete" code:

```
 if(marks.size() > 0)
    {
        for(Student student: students)
        {
            ArrayList<String> subjectNames = new ArrayList<>();
            String studentFullName = student.getSurName() + "\t" + student.getName();
            studentNames.add(studentFullName);

            for(Subject subject: subjects)
            {
                String subjectName = subject.getName() + "\t" + 0;
                subjectNames.add(subjectName);
            }
            markListHashMap.put(studentFullName, subjectNames);
        }

        for(Mark mark: marks)
        {
            Student student = dbHelper.getStudent(mark.getStudentRegister());
            String fullName = student.getSurName() + "\t" + student.getName();
            Subject subject = dbHelper.getSubject(mark.getSubjectId());
            String subjectName = subject.getName() + "\t";
            subjectName = subjectName + dbHelper.getTotal(mark);
            ArrayList<String> subjects = (ArrayList<String>) markListHashMap.get(fullName);
            int index = 0;

            for(String s: subjects)
            {
                String s1 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\t"));
                String s2 = subjectName.substring(0, subjectName.indexOf("\t"));

                if(s1 == s2)
                {
                    s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\t"));
                    s = s + subjectName.substring(subjectName.indexOf("\t") + 1, subjectName.length());
                    markListHashMap.get(fullName).set(index, s);
                }
                else
                    index++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If `s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\t"))` gives you an index error, it is because your string does not contain `\t`. It is not **caused by** the equals operator.

Comment: s does contain "\t" because I also watch it's value while debugging step by step and you can see that in the statement String subjectName = subject.getName() + "\t" + 0; I did add "\t" to it.

Comment: Then it's a different line that is throwing the exception.

Comment: How can it give you `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the previous two lines? If it gives SIOOBE on the first line the second line will not be reached - if it gives SIOOBE on the second line it cannot have happened on the first line...

Comment: It's giving me SIOOBE on the first line if I use .equals to compare s1 and s2 and If I use == operator I don't get any exception, but the if statement body is not executed even if the 2 strings are equal, they have the same length and same value "Mathematics"

Answer (score 1):

You are getting **[StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)**

> Thrown by String methods to indicate that an index is either negative
>   or greater than the size of the string.

Problem coming from

```
s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\t")); //this line
```

1. Make sure your **`s`** having `\t`
2. `s` having **Length()** and not **null** .

.

Comment: What about the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException wich is the main problem

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you s1 and s2 is not null and having length>=0
add below line before comparing both variables (s1 and s2)

```
if(s1!=null && s2!=null && s1.length()>=0 && s2.length>=0){
  if(s1 == s2){
       s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\t"));
       s = s + subjectName.substring(subjectName.indexOf("\t") + 1, subjectName.length());
       markListHashMap.get(fullName).set(index, s);
       }
        else
           index++;
  }
```

Comment: I see both s1 and s2 values become "Mathematics" before the if statement while debugging step-by-step and watching their values, but the if statement ignores it as if they are not equal, that's why I wrote "a weird problem"

Answer (score 0):

The condition `s1 == s2` will never be true, since the two lines:

```
String s1 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\t"));
String s2 = subjectName.substring(0, subjectName.indexOf("\t"));
```

create different `String` objects. These `String` objects may appear to be equal (i.e. contain the same letters), but `==` just compares object references. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

---

The reason for the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is in the way that you create your resulting string if the condition is fullfilled (i.e. if you do `s1.equals(s2)`):

```
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\t"));
s = s + subjectName.substring(subjectName.indexOf("\t") + 1, subjectName.length());
```

This takes the part **before** the `"\t"` from `s` and appends the part **after** the `"\t"` from `subjectName`, thereby effectively removing the `"\t"`. Now if the same string is encountered while iterating `subjects` for the second mark there is no longer any `"\t"` in your string and you get an SIOOBE.

It would not happen if you were to write it as:

```
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\t"));
s = s + subjectName.substring(subjectName.indexOf("\t"), subjectName.length());
```

But, since you have just previously established that `s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\t"))` is the same as `subjectName.substring(0, subjectName.indexOf("\t"))`, you could skip this altogether and just write

```
s = subjectName;
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that mistake and fixed it a while ago, but I fixed it like this: s = s + "\t" + subjectName.substring(subjectName.indexOf("\t") + 1, subjectName.length()); I tend to overcomplicate things sometimes :D